# Unity | Get height from Heightmap at current mouse poisition

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I wanted to develop a small game. In this game I wanted to include a procedural map generation. It all worked great.

But now I want to find out the height of the heightmap at the mouse position and that doesn't make any sense and I don't understand it

Here a example:
[Heightmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbnrf.png)

I wrote this script in the void Update()

```cs
 if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            float x = (mousePos.x / Screen.width) * mapWidth;
            float y = (mousePos.y / Screen.height) * mapHeight;
            //get height at mouse position
            float[,] noiseMap = Noise.GenerateNoiseMap (mapWidth, mapHeight, seed, noiseScale, octaves, persistance, lacunarity, offset);
            float height = noiseMap[(int)x, (int)y];
            Debug.Log(height);
        }
```

When I try this script above I get very strange values.
Like:

[Here at a very black or high place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCDJh.png) i get: 0.5208731

[And here at a white place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OhWt.png) i get: 0.7484959

But then:
[at this white place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka88Q.png) i get: 0.2161063

Something isn't working here and i don't understand it.

Comment: How are you generating the visible representation of the noise map? Input.mousePosition is [0,0] in the bottom left. Is it possible your heather map had [0,0] in the top left?

Comment: Im using a plane with a material on it

Comment: Use the Physics.Raycast method to get the position and coordinates of the object.